# Define enum constant body in JCodeModel

Tags: java, jcodemodel

I'd like to create the following Java source code using JCodeModel

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FIRST_CONSTANT {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "first";
        }
    },
    SECOND_CONSTANT {

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "second";
        }
    };

    public abstract String toString();
}
```

But [JEnumConstant](https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JEnumConstant.html) does not expose methods to define the enum constant's body.

Is there a way to achieve this? Moreover I noticed that JCodeModel does not support certain JDK 7 oder JDK 8 features like try with resources. Is there an alternative source code generation utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are correct. the Latest version of JCodeModel (2.6) does not have the capabilities to generate enum constant methods.